# Why MediaPlayer keeps playing when app is closed by the user?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I've built a radio app which plays live music from a stream with the help of `MediaPlayer`.

The problem started when I created a service which job is to execute a block of code when app is closed by the user(Its job is to delete the notification). In this service I am using **startForeground()** method in order to make it as a *foreground service* and therefore keep it alive as long as the app runs (because if I don't, the OS will kill it in 1 minute).

But the problem now is that when the user closes the app the `MediaPlayer` keeps playing. My app didn't have this behavior before adding the **startForeground()** method in the service.

I don't know if this would be helpful but if I add a System.exit(0) in the onTaskRemoved() method when app is closed by the user music stops and I get a notification from OS which says that my app is consuming battery.

Does anyone know why my application has this peculiar behavior? Why the application process isn't killed??

```
public class OnClearFromRecentService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "onClearFromRecentServic";
    private NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManagerCompat;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mNotificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service Started");
        startForeground(2001, new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNELID)
    .setContentTitle("title").setContentText("contentText").build());
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //Put code here which will be executed when app is closed from user.
        Log.d(TAG, "onTaskRemoved was executed ");
        mNotificationManagerCompat.cancelAll();
        stopSelf();
    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml** :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nikolouts.kwnstantinos.plutoradio">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$NotificationReceiver" />

        <activity android:name=".ChatActivity"/>
        <service android:name=".OnClearFromRecentService" android:stopWithTask="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the user closed the app"? Please describe exactly what the user does to "close the app"

Comment: @DavidWasser I mean that the user is closing the app by swiping it from the recent apps list

Comment: post your manifest please.

Comment: @DavidWasser Sure, I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in your manifest 'stopWithTask="false"'. This tells Android not to stop your Service when the user swipes the app from the list of recent tasks. Set this to "true"

Comment: Indeed the music now stops but the onTaskRemoved() callback method isn't executed ;/ 
I guess it's my lucky day because if I set the same notification id for the foreground notification and the audio player notification the notification is deleted when service stops . Therefore it's working perfectly!

Comment: `onTaskRemoved()` will not be called if you set `stopWithTask="true"`. In this case, Android just kills the OS process hosting the `Service` and the other components (`Activity`, etc.). When it does that your `Service` is no longer running as a foreground `Service`, so Android removes the foreground `Service` notification. Looks like your problem is solved.